# Remove white outline JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jtextpane

I have JFrame with a JTextPane in it.

Kind of a very simple text editor.

Now the problem is there is a very thin white border around the frame.

This is ok if the color of the text pane is white but if i make the text pane dark colored then the white outline looks very bad.

Here is my code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Try{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Try");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0 ,0 ));
        JTextPane tpane = new JTextPane();
        tpane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        tpane.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        JScrollPane scp = new JScrollPane(tpane);
        frame.add(scp);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried setUndecorated but that removes the title bar not the outline.

This is the white outline i am talking about :

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: `scp.setBorder(null);` ?

Comment: @user15358848 nope doesnt work

Comment: does for me (maybe Look&Feel)... but there is something more in that screen shot (`ol` ??)

Comment: @user15358848 that `ol` is part of  a icon on my desktop background ignore it

Comment: @user15358848 i rechecked with setBorder and found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this is caused due to the default border of the scroll pane. We can get rid of it by setting an empty border to it.

This is the updated code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Try{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Try");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0 ,0 ));
        JTextPane tpane = new JTextPane();
        tpane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        tpane.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        JScrollPane scp = new JScrollPane(tpane);
        scp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        frame.add(scp);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: An answer should include the reason for the change. People should not have to compare line by line to see what is different. So your answer should be that you are using an EmptyBorder and the code shows how you use it.

Comment: @camickr is it ok now?

Comment: (1+) better. And you can "accept" your own answer. This lets people see more easily that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score -2):

Add another border in JFrames and define color for it, I hope It will work